How to find the text from a label in selenium pytest
I've a requirement to capture the payment ID from the text in an element using Selenium, python, pytest UI. The text is in the form, "Payment 3022594".
I was trying something like this.
PAYMENT_ID_TEXT_XPATH = "//div[@class='BottomLayoutHeaderWrapper']//h5[text()='Payment']"

paymentId = self.get_element(self.PAYMENT_ID_TEXT_XPATH, page)
if paymentId:
    paymentId = paymentId.strip()
paymentIdValue = paymentId[8:]

This doesn't always work because sometimes paymentId is null resulting in TypeError,
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

in the line where I am extracting paymentIdValue.
Is there better way to capture the payment ID from the text?
The Payment ID will always be appended to the text "Payment" in the UI.

You need to share the relevant HTML. How is the H5 text "Payment" according to your locator but you also expect it to be, "Payment ID (3022594)"?




Payment
3022594

All relevant details should be edited into the question and not just left to the comments so future readers can see all info related to the question. Please edit your question and add the HTML, properly formatted.

The only way I could see this working is with the changes below,

Given the HTML you provided, h5[text()='Payment'] will never work because it's expecting the full text in the H5 to be "Payment" and you've stated that it should be, "Payment 3022594". You need to change that to contains() so it can be located.
if paymentId: will not work because if the element is not found, the previous line, self.get_element(), will throw an exception.
To get the text from an element you need to use element.text.

Updated code
PAYMENT_ID_TEXT_XPATH = "//div[@class='BottomLayoutHeaderWrapper']//h5[contains(text(),'Payment')]"

paymentId = self.get_element(self.PAYMENT_ID_TEXT_XPATH, page).text.strip()[8:]

